# How do i disable a button after i have clicked it 2 times?

Tags: javascript, html, counter, appendchild, disable

I have a project for school, which consists of making a text editor. I added a menu button, which is supposed to be clicked and disabled after clicking it 2 times, so it wont append more and more childs of the menu button.
Here is the code:

```js
let btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.type = 'button';
btn.value = 'Open Menu';
btn.onclick = () => {
let btn2 = document.createElement('input');
btn2.type = 'button';
btn2.value = 'New Text';
document.body.appendChild(btn2);
}
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

As you can see, i have a button that after it gets clicked, appends a new button to the body of the document. And if you click it 2 or 3 times, 3 new buttons gets appended, which is buggy.
I tried adding a counter like this:

```js
let counter = 0;
if (counter === 2) {
document.querySelector("button")[0].disabled = "disabled"; || document.querySelector("button")[0].disabled = true;
}
```

Well, that didn't seem to work out as expected.
Any ideas on how to get this working?
Thank you

Comment: you probably should count how many elements are present in the body instead using this counter variable out of the scope. Also, counter variable should be on a parent level otherwise will be reset on every time the user clicks on the button.

Answer (score 3):

You should initialize the `counter` outside of the `onclick` event handler. Then you can add this code in the end of `onclick` event handler:

```js
counter++;
if (counter === 2) btn.disabled = true;
```

```js
const btn = document.createElement('input');
let counter = 0;
btn.type = 'button';
btn.value = 'Open Menu';
btn.onclick = () => {
  let btn2 = document.createElement('input');
  btn2.type = 'button';
  btn2.value = 'New Text';
  document.body.appendChild(btn2);
  counter++;
  if (counter === 2) btn.disabled = true;
}
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```